# Is it possible to animate the vertical size of the Silverlight plugin?

Tags: silverlight

Would like to have the plugin change size as part of an internal Silverlight animation.  Possible?  Can't seem to find answer.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do that. You're much better off having the plugin take up 100% of the window and then set it to Windowless = true so that you can overlay the HTML.

I was recently moving the plugin around on the page while scrolling and it was very choppy, but when I switched to moving the html content up and down the page instead it was smooth.

You could animate the size by calling out the Javascript and using a DispatchTimer, but like I said that would probably be choppy and there is probably a better way.